# Delete event not updating datatable rows

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

In primefaces I  have a confirm dialogue box and when I confirm the delete button my rows in the database are deleted however the page is not updated. Am I missing something that is not updating the page. My dialogue box is defined as below.

```
<h:form id="searchForm">
    <p:commandButton id="showDialogButton" value="Delete Data" onclick="confirmation.show()" 
                    style="margin:20px" type="button" immediate="true" />
                <p:confirmDialog id="confirmDialog" message="Are you sure you want to delete all the data for this submission?"  
                            header="Initiating delete process" severity="alert" widgetVar="confirmation">      
                    <p:commandButton id="confirm" value="Yes Sure" update=":searchForm:rowDataTable" oncomplete="confirmation.hide()"  
                                actionListener="#{myDataBean.deleteData}" immediate="true" ajax="true"/>  
                    <p:commandButton id="decline" value="Not Yet" onclick="confirmation.hide()" type="button" immediate="true"/>   

                </p:confirmDialog>
```

In the same form I have defined a datatable

```
<p:dataTable var="row"
                    value="#{myDataBean.entries}"
                    id="rowDataTable" paginator="true"
                    rows="30"
                    paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                    rowsPerPageTemplate="10,20,30" 
                    >
```

which has a subtable inside it that shows all the data

```
<p:subTable id="rowSubTable" var="details" value="#{row.data}">
```

In my bean I have the following action listener. After the action listener is completed it calls the load intial view method to reload the data because of a pre render view event i have defined.

```
public List<SubmissionRow> entries = new ArrayList<SubmissionRow>();

public void loadInitialView() {
    if (!postback) {
        List<Submission> data = loadData();
        //sort data and build entries list
    }       
}

@Transactional
    public void deleteData(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        submission.deleteRows(submissionBean.getSubmission());
        entries.clear();
        postback = false;
    }
```

Comment: did you debug to check that the data array does not contain the deleted row after you call loadData()? why are you using transactional annotation? the submission attribute is a EJB? or what?

Comment: Yes my entries is empty as i clear it on the return from the db call. Yes the submission is a jpa entity thus use transactional.

Comment: Sorry just re read my answer and yes the data array is empty after loadData call.

Comment: so the bean contains the right data, but it's not reflected on datatable? did you check in firebug if there's any eror on client side? the ajax response is ok?

Answer (score 0):

As there was only the table visible on my page I just reloaded the page from the action listener using the external context. This way the datatable got updated.